# Logs guaranteed delivery using Logstash/Redis in shipper node

Tags: logging, redis, logstash, log-shipping, log-analysis

What do you think folks, about placing Redis in each Logstash shipper node to ensure a guaranteed logs delivery?

Comment: Can you describe your question more clearly? So far the logstash recommend that the redis can put at indexer node.

Comment: Logstash recommend redis at indexer node for load balancing.

Comment: My concern is about reliable shipping, I don't want to use a classic  RELP/rsyslog. Any suggestion to ensure no logs loss?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using logstash or logstash-forwarder as your shipper into a centralized logstash, you typically don't need a broker like redis.  The shippers will detect when logstash is unable to accept more events.  It will maintain a pointer to the current log location, and continue when the bottleneck is removed.

If you have logs that don't buffer (syslog, snmptrap, etc), then a broker makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees form the point of ingestion (generating downstream event) to the point of storing in Elasticsearch or Hadoop. This is a distributed system with many points of failure. Unfortunately it is up to you to handle reliability and recovery. There is a CR pending with logstash to improve current situation.

https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2609

Nonetheless, logstash acts as originator or aggregator of events for the downstream system. You need to solve reliability based on your system design and SLA. If you were using a full stack product like Splunk, the issue would be handled by the vendor.(at least i was told but yet to test for myself ;))